# C# Powerpoint 2007 Copy Slides with Formatting

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

So I have been able to get slides copied over from PPT 2010 with the `ExecuteMso("PasteSourceFormatting");` command just fine, sadly this does not work for 2007. I have been able to open up the Source Presentation slides and copy and paste all the content into the Destination Presentation just fine. But the formatting is just off on certain things, color, text size, images resizing. I've also noticed that if the Destination Presentation that I'm attempting to paste into has a Master slide that it is now applied to the newly created slides from the copy/paste Source Presentation. I have yet to find a way that I am able to copy over the master slide from the Source Presentation to the Destination on and tell it to use the new master slides for the slides being pasted it. The closest I can get to it is to copy over the Layout, ColorScheme, and Design. But they still are not formatted correctly do to the missing master slide.

How do I copy over the PPT slides and keep the source format (using source master slide) in PPT 2007?

Comment: please be [explicit about your question](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#explicit).

Comment: "I've also noticed that if the Destination Presentation that I'm attempting to paste into has a Master slide ..."   ALL presentations have at least one Master slide, so the presence or absence of one isn't relevant.